# Image Change On Button Click In Android

Tags: android, imageview

I'm new to android and am making a simple app.  I'm trying to change the image (in an imageview) on a button click.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    frown = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


}
public void action(View view)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), buttontest, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    frown.setImageResource(R.drawable.chimpy);

}
```

"action" is being called via XML with the "android:onClick"[insert method here]" for my button

The button works fine and I get my toast, but the image stays the same.

Comment: can you post a snippet of your xml?

Comment: That is a bit weird. Have you checked the DDMS debug output?

Comment: It should be fine... have you checked to make sure "chimpy" and the default drawable aren't the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the drawable to something standard e.g. android.R.drawable.btn_default.
Does it chnage Now?
I am sure you are having some issues with R.drawable.chimpy.

Answer (score 0):

You must use .png image and you can go with the following code snippet:

```
frown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            frown.setBackgroundDrawable(R.id.chimpy);
        }
});
```

If it is not working, just tell me...!